# Execution higher version of jar file on the server

Tags: java, exception, server, executable-jar, runnable-jar

I have a jar file of version 1.8 and I want to execute it on the server. But I'm having java version 1.7 on the server.

How can I fix this?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/inno/server/Server : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:803)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:14
```

Comment: Two options: 1. Upgrade your server's java version 2. Downgrade your code's target version - there's no intermediate fix

Comment: how can i install jdk 1.8 on server?

Comment: Roughly speaking: the same way you install it on your local machine. Strictly speaking: speak to your sysadmin